# Coredata alias syntax

Tags: ios, core-data

I would like to set custom name to my property while fetching that property.
I know we will able to do in sqlite, is this possible in core data 
Is anyone know equivalent core data query for

```
SELECT column_name AS alias_name FROM table_name
```

Comment: Why do you want to do that? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: It is possible, using an `NSExpression` / `NSExpressionDescription` and the `propertiesToFetch` / `resultType` properties of a fetch.  The result will be an array of NSDictionary objects, each of which uses a key (eg. "alias_name") to access the value from the "column_name" property of the "table_name" objects underlying the fetch.  Is that what you want?

Comment: yes @pbasdf I got it myself. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

Just use as mentioned in the comments from @pbasdf `NSExpression` and `NSExpressionDescription`

```
NSFetchRequest *request = ...;

NSExpression *expression = [NSExpression expressionForKeyPath:originalPropertyName];
NSExpressionDescription *expressionDescription = [[NSExpressionDescription alloc] init];
expressionDescription.name = newResultKeyName;
expressionDescription.expression = expression;
expressionDescription.expressionResultType = NSInteger64AttributeType; //The result type

request.resultType = NSDictionaryResultType;
request.propertiesToFetch = @[expressionDescription, ...];
```

Answer (score 0):

The SQLite store backing Core Data is hidden from you so you can't interact with it directly. The whole point is that you have defined entities that your app uses, and that's what Core Data works with.

So, no, you can't do that with Core Data.